# ¿Cómo puedo filtrar una observable list con un valor seleccionado de un ComboBox? FXML

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Estoy haciendo un proyecto conjunto de Java FXML en el que tengo una ObservableList que me muestra una lista de "vuelos" que coge de una base de datos interna.

```
 private ObservableList<distribuciovols> llistaVolsClients;

llistaVolsClients = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
filtradaLlistaVolsClients = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

conexio = new Conbd();

SeguimentVol.setItems(llistaVolsClients);
        
OrigenSeguimentVol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<distribuciovols, String>("idorigen"));
DestiSeguimentVol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<distribuciovols, String>("iddesti"));
EstatSeguimentVol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<distribuciovols, String>("estat"));
```

Encima de la tabla, tengo dos ComboBox con los que puedes seleccionar un String.

¿Cómo podría coger este String y filtrar la lista para que aparezcan los vuelos seleccionados?

Comment: con un listener que escuche cambios en combobox y que gatille forEach en ObservableList()

Answer (score 0):

**Filtrar `OservableList` con su método`filtered()`**

[image: filtrar list]

Cada vez que se cambia el valor de `comboBox` se obtiene el valor seleccionado y se utiliza para hacer un `FilteredList` que se obtiene mediante `filtered()` que ve si cada `String` de su `ObservableList<String>` contiene el valor de `comBox.getValue()`. si es así añade el `String` a `FilteredList` . salvo si es "Ninguno" ese valor se salta al principio para que limpie la lista derecha . Una vez completada `FilteredList` se le pasa a `vuelosFiltrados`  y se actualiza la lista derecha

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        ObservableList<String> vuelos = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ObservableList<String> vuelosFiltarados = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ListView<String> lista = new ListView<>(vuelos);
        ListView<String> listaFiltrada = new ListView<>(vuelosFiltarados);

        vuelos.addAll("Santiago", "Almería", "Buenos Aires ", "Santiago ", "Almería",
                "Buenos Aires ", "Paris", "Buenos Aires ", "Santiago ", "Almería", "Buenos Aires ", "Paris");
        ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();

        comboBox.getItems().addAll("Ninguno", "Santiago ", "Almería", "Paris");
        HBox hBox = new HBox(comboBox, lista, listaFiltrada);

        comboBox.valueProperty().addListener(e
                -> {
            String test = comboBox.getValue();
            if (!test.contains("Ninguno")) {
                listaFiltrada.getItems().clear();
                FilteredList<String> filtered = vuelos.filtered((t) -> {
                    return t.contains(test);
                    
                });
                vuelosFiltarados.addAll(filtered);
            } else {

                listaFiltrada.getItems().clear();
            }

        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(hBox, 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```